# have one preoblem when i run vaadin app on vsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vaadin, lit-element

i have this problem when i try to run vaadin app with visual studio "The version of Vaadin you are using in this project is not supported by Vaadin Studio yet.",I changed the version but the problem persists. please someone can help me

Comment: Q: Did you install the VSCode plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vaadin.studio? The latest version is alpha 0.1.1, 4/15/2021.  Q: Did you create a Vaadin Fusion project with LitElement templates?  Q: Have you installed all the prerequisites? Node.js v12++, Java JDK v1.8 ++, Apache Mavenv3.6++?

Comment: i have everything except maven, thanks i will install it now

Comment: Be advised, you might need to back *DOWN* to an *EARLIER* version of Vaadin in order to use the Vaadin Studio VSCode plugin.  The link I cited above mentions `The project needs to use Vaadin 19 or above...`.  The latest version on https://vaadin.com is 23.0.10.  That might be *TOO* high...  Look here for other releases: https://github.com/vaadin/platform/tags

Answer (score 3):

Vaadin Studio hasn't been further developed since the initial alpha version was released. There has been newer versions of Vaadin since then that are not compatible with Studio.

Since it's not recommended to use those older Vaadin versions, this also implies that use of Vaadin Studio is not recommended.

Comment: yes it's right sir

Answer (score 0):

it's like Leif Åstrand said, so I left vscode for eclipse and I followed the steps of the following tutorial:
https://crunchify.com/mavenmvn-clean-install-update-project-and-project-clean-options-in-eclipse-ide-to-fix-any-dependency-issue/

and I created a configuration file where I specified a new free port since the 8080 is used.

thank you all for your help